# How to pass a variable in PHP to another page without using $_POST?

Tags: php, variables

How does one pass a PHP variable stored on one page that is NOT in a form, go to another page where a function uses it?

The reason I need this is so a user can adjust their form they are using by adding more rows with a submit button.

This is what I want to achieve:

- $maxrows = stores the total amount of rows currently on the page
- user presses "add more rows button"
- another page is loaded which has a function which adds $maxrows + 5
- once complete, the page redirects to the form
- the form redisplays the page with 5 more rows

Any ideas how this can be implemented?

Thanks

**Preferably not in a session if possible!**

Comment: Thanks - im using a framework and the session class I built is purely for login. Im too scared to put any other data into the session that is not needed.

Comment: Give it a prefix then so you have no chance of conflicts.

Something like `$_SESSION["my_max_rows"] = 13;` will be safe.
If you don't want to change the name on your pages you can just assign it back out. `$max_rows = $_SESSION["my_max_rows"];`

Comment: Thanks im just creating a new session class like you said which will deal with form customization. :)

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer if one helped you.

Answer (score 3):

I would use [sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php).

Answer (score 2):

you can use jQuery + ajax to achieve this. Here when you click on add more rows it will add up just dome elements with dynamic names. The concept can be understood from http://charlie.griefer.com/blog/2009/09/17/jquery-dynamically-adding-form-elements/

Comment: jQuery would be good in this case. Much cleaner then jumping around pages to change the look of a form.

Answer (score 1):

Use it with `GET` parameters - include the variable in the URL that loads your new page like

```
http://example.com/file.php?maxrows=10
```

In `file.php` you get it by using `$_GET` instead of `$_POST`

Comment: Its just a variable in my php code its not set by an input box or any form.

How do I get it then?

Thanks

Comment: you said *---another page is loaded which has a function which adds $maxrows + 5* - the URL for this page could be generated with the parameter in the end - or, as Drazisil said - you could use sessions

Comment: How do I generate the url with my variable at the end then? Thanks I tried googling $_get but nothing relates to my situation when im trying to pass a global variable to another page. Thanks

Comment: Anything with a querystring becomes a $_GET
`page.php?a=moo` becomes `$_GET['moo']`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `$_GET` instead of `$_POST`.

You pass the variable in to the page via the url:

`someurl.com/page.php?somevar=hello`

Then in `page.php` you can use `$_GET['somevar']` which will equal `"hello"`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a session.

Put `start_session();` at the beginning of your script.

You can store the number of rows in `$_SESSION['max_rows']`.